# Does Cubase 8 import Cubase 7 projects?

Tags: cubase, compatibility

I have many Cubase 7 AI projects. If I get Cubase 8 Artist, will I be able to open that projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine.

See [this article](https://www.steinberg.net/en/support/knowledgebase_new/show_details/kb_show/compatibility-and-interchangeability-of-project-files/kb_back/2020.html) for official Steinberg notes on compatibility (the image thumbnail doesn't seem to work, but it works if you click it). Here is the compatibility chart from the article:

[image]

In general the rule of thumb is that you can always open old projects created with a previous version in a newer version, but the other way around is more uncertain.